# Terse approach to validating data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Before using arguments passed into my JavaScript functions, I'm currently doing at least two, in most cases three checks -- see below:

```
export const doSomething(firstName, lastName, age) {

  if(typeof firstName !== "undefined" && firstName !== null && firstName !== "") {
     // Use firstName
  }
}
```

Is this the proper way to do it? It's pretty verbose and I was wondering if there's terser approach.

Comment: you could check out a static type checker like [flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

I think only checking the string type and empty is more elegant. While seeing your condition first thing came to my mind was, firstName could be array, object, function.

```js
function doSomething(firstName, lastName, age) {

  if(typeof firstName === "string" && firstName !== "") {
     // Use firstName
     console.log(firstName);
  }else {
    console.log("Empty or undefined");
  }
}
doSomething("");
doSomething("Atiq");
doSomething();
```